# How to convert from character to as.Date

Tags: r, tidyverse

Please consider this small data.frame. I am trying to make a year column based on a
SampleDate that is already formatted as.Date, however, the newly created year column
turns into a character and not as.Date. Question, how do I preserve the format for the year column?
I get an error when trying to convert to as.Date.
My code

```
a <- structure(list(SampleRowID = c(109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109), 
               SampleDate = structure(c(15803, 15803, 15803, 15803, 15803, 
                                        15803), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                      -6L))
glimpse(a)
$ SampleRowID <dbl> 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109
$ SampleDate  <date> 2013-04-08, 2013-04-08, 2013-04-08, 2013-04-08, 2013-04-08, 2013-04-08
#SampleDate is a date format

#Adding a year column doesn't keep the date format...is a character
a$year <- format(a$SampleDate,"%Y")
 glimpse(a)
 $ SampleRowID <dbl> 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109
$ SampleDate  <date> 2013-04-08, 2013-04-08, 2013-04-08, 2013-04-08, 2013-04-08, 2013-04-08
$ year        <chr> "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013"
```

Trying to convert year to as.Date format throws an error

> a$year <- as.Date(a$year)
> Error in charToDate(x) :
> character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: so you want to turn it into a date column, but make it not look like a date column, just show the year? Why not just keep it as a character or a number if it matters

Comment: I need the year column to be as.Date format because I querying a database using year but I am getting an error because 'year' is not being recognized as date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert with the `parse_date` function after transforming the proper format with the `lubridate::year` function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

a %>% 
  mutate(year = paste0(year(SampleDate),"-01-01") %>% parse_date) %>% 
  glimpse()

Rows: 6
Columns: 3
$ SampleRowID <dbl> 109, 109, 109, 109, 109, 109
$ SampleDate  <date> 2013-04-08, 2013-04-08, 2013-04-08, 2013-04-0…
$ year        <date> 2013-01-01, 2013-01-01, 2013-01-01, 2013-01-…
```

Answer (score 1):

You can paste '-01-01' onto the end of a year to create valid dates, and then convert those to date type:

```
> a$year <- as.Date(paste0(a$year, "-01-01"))
> a$year

[1] "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01"
[6] "2013-01-01
```

Comment: I already did that @Mark. Notice the my SampleDate column is already formatted as.Date. The year is the column that I want formatted as Date. Is that even possible?

Comment: @Salvador read my answer again. Note the column I'm working with

Comment: a date, both in real life and in R code, has a year, a month, and a day. Saying you want to turn a year into a date has no more meaning than me saying I want to turn the first of April into a date

Comment: Got you @Mark, I overlooked the output all ending in 01. That could work. I will test to see if my database take that. Thanks